# The <sup> tag suddenly doesn't work?

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering, formatting

I'm an avid user (probably *too* avid) of the markdown `<sup>` tag to superscript some text. Usually for footnotes, which don't have any built-in support.

Suddenly, some of my uses of the `<sup>` tag just don't seem to working. See for example the bottom of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431599/efficiently-dividing-unsigned-value-by-a-power-of-two-rounding-up) where I have:

```
<sup>0</sup> Of course...

<sup>1</sup> I'm also ...

<sup>2</sup> In general ...
```

For me, on Firefox (linux desktop), Chrome (linux desktop, mobile) it always renders as:

[image]

That is, the 0th footnote is showing up as superscript, but the 1st and 2nd aren't. The same issue shows in the preview and I've messed around a ton with copying and pasting, trying different things, but couldn't conclude exactly what breaks it.

**What's up?**

Let's try it here:

> <sup>0</sup> Of course, this notation doesn't actually work in C where
>   `/` truncates the result so the `ceiling` does nothing. So consider
>   that pseudo-notation rather than straight C.
>
> <sup>1</sup> I'm also interested solutions where all types are
>   `uint32_t` rather than `uint64_t`.
>
> <sup>2</sup> In general, any `p` and `q` where `p + q >= 2^64` causes
>   an issue, due to overflow.

Weird, it works (even without the quote)...

Comment: You have a typo in your markdown in your question: `<sup>1<sup>`.

Comment: You were missing a closing tag.

Comment: Gah. I never though to look up earlier in the document. Any idea why that would make *some* of the following tags work (the 0 in the footnote), but then break even later ones?

Answer (score 2):

In [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431599/efficiently-dividing-unsigned-value-by-a-power-of-two-rounding-up) there was one `<sup>` tag which should have been a closing tag, but it wasn't:

> ```
> would something like the following function<sup>1<sup>
> ```

I changed that to:

> ```
> would something like the following function<sup>1</sup>
> ```

and now it works fine.

Comment: Ha, I see, so the damage was up earlier in the file. Out of curiosity, why does that break some, but not all, of the later `<sup>` usages?

Comment: @BeeOnRope because HTML interpretation works in mysterious ways; that's a basic side effect of the fact that the HTML specs are designed to allow content to contain faults. I wouldn't give it too much thought.